# Natural transformation between functors induces homotopy between maps on the nerve

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, higher-category-theory

I'm learning what is the nerve of a category and I saw that if we have a natural transformation between two functors F and G, then we have a homotopy between the maps N(F) and N(G) where N(-) denotes the nerve construction. However, I wasn't able to find a proof. Does someone has a reference in which it is proved ?

Comment: Do you know that a natural transformation of functors $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ is the same thing as a functor $[1] \times \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$, where $[1]$ is the category $\{ 0 \to 1 \}$? How about the fact that $N$ preserves products?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that. As N is a right adjoint, it commutes with limits and in particular products and it is obvious that N([1]) is homeomorphic to the interval [0;1]. I just need to see clearly why this is a homotopy from N(F) to N(G). I will write it properly to understand it well. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm glad you got the point, but just so we are clear, $N([1])$ is not _homeomorphic_ to the interval. It is not even a topological space.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i wanted to say the geometric realization of N([1]).